# Entity Framework and Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint error in many-to-many relationship

Tags: entity-framework, foreign-keys, ef-code-first, many-to-many, cascade

I'm trying to create next model for a web app:

- A company can create customers and categories (for customers).
- A customer can belong to several categories.
- Several customers can belong to the same category.

Entities:

```
public class Company
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int CompanyId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int CompanyId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}
```

Data context:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Customer> Customer { get; set; }

    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString, throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

When I run the app and try to get a company, I get the next error:

**Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.CustomerCategories_dbo.Categories_Category_Id' on table 'CustomerCategories' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.**

I don't understand why I getting this error. I think it is a many-to-many relationship which is the problem. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try making the CompanyId  nullable in the Category entity

Comment: Thank you @Vince , that works, but I don't know why. Which is the problem with CompanyId? Should I do this practice with all foreign keys, like Customer.CompanyId?

Comment: Try to draw out the diagram and it should be clearer why this is a problem. It is a bit complicated to word. But in short you are saying each category must have a company, each customer also must have a company, however each customer can also have many categories. I would suggest splitting your categories completely like this: https://imgur.com/a/cGB4KIb
edit, no you should not do this for all foreign keys

Comment: Actually the Error is well described: "may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths".
This means, when you delete a company, the cascading deletes the corresponding category and customer. Then when the customer gets deleted, the coresponding join table entrys between customer and category gets also deleted. Since the same is going on on the category side, it could theoretically be, that two cascade paths point to the same entry in the join table. Therefore, MSSQL prevents you from creating this cascading constellation. MSSQL is just designed like that.Other DBs like MySql allows such scenarios.

Comment: See also: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/100493/why-cant-we-have-multiple-cascade-paths