# How to disable cascade deletion for Many to Many relationship EF Core Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I feel that there is a ton of ambiguity in Stack Overflow on questions regarding disabling the cascading deletion feature by EF Core 6 for many-many relationships. I've spent hours wrestling with this question and cannot find an answer on the Microsoft docs or on Stack Overflow. How can I change my code to disable cascade deletion on my many-many relationship below?

SuggestionModel.cs

```
[Key]
public long SuggestionId { get; set; }
...
public ICollection<UserModel> UserVotes { get; set; } = new HashSet<UserModel>();
...
```

UserModel.cs

```
[Key]
public long UserId { get; set; }
...
public ICollection<SuggestionModel> VotedOnSuggestions { get; set; } = new List<SuggestionModel>();
...
```

DbConnection.cs (DbContext class)

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   ...
   modelBuilder.Entity<UserModel>().HasData(user1, user2, user3, user4);
   modelBuilder.Entity<SuggestionModel>().HasData(suggestion1, suggestion2, suggestion3, suggestion4, suggestion5);
   modelBuilder.Entity<SuggestionModel>().HasMany(s => s.UserVotes).WithMany(u => u.VotedOnSuggestions)
        .UsingEntity(e => e.HasData(
            new { VotedOnSuggestionsSuggestionId = 4L, UserVotesUserId = 1L },
            new { VotedOnSuggestionsSuggestionId = 4L, UserVotesUserId = 2L },
            new { VotedOnSuggestionsSuggestionId = 4L, UserVotesUserId = 3L },
            new { VotedOnSuggestionsSuggestionId = 5L, UserVotesUserId = 1L },
            new { VotedOnSuggestionsSuggestionId = 5L, UserVotesUserId = 2L },
            new { VotedOnSuggestionsSuggestionId = 5L, UserVotesUserId = 3L },
            new { VotedOnSuggestionsSuggestionId = 5L, UserVotesUserId = 4L }
            ));
}
```

The exact error

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint
'FK_SuggestionModelUserModel_Users_UserVotesUserId' on table 'SuggestionModelUserModel'
may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO
ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
```

SQL Command that caused the error

```
 Failed executing DbCommand (10ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text',
 CommandTimeout='30']
 CREATE TABLE [SuggestionModelUserModel] ( 
 [UserVotesUserId] bigint NOT NULL,
 [VotedOnSuggestionsSuggestionId] bigint NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT 
 [PK_SuggestionModelUserModel] PRIMARY KEY ([UserVotesUserId], 
 [VotedOnSuggestionsSuggestionId]),
 CONSTRAINT [FK_SuggestionModelUserModel_Suggestions_VotedOnSuggestionsSuggestionId] 
 FOREIGN KEY ([VotedOnSuggestionsSuggestionId]) REFERENCES [Suggestions] 
 ([SuggestionId]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT [FK_SuggestionModelUserModel_Users_UserVotesUserId] FOREIGN KEY 
 ([UserVotesUserId]) REFERENCES [Users] ([UserId]) ON DELETE CASCADE
 );
```

EDIT
I have disabled the Nullable Reference feature in my projects.

Answer (score 1):

I found that marking all my foreign keys as nullable fixed the issue. I found this question [Entity Framework and Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint error in many-to-many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58689986/entity-framework-and-introducing-foreign-key-constraint-error-in-many-to-many-re) to be really helpful!